# Get row reference from validated drop down list

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

So I have two sheets, `masterIngredientList` and `shoppingList`. I have data validation in my `shoppingList` which is bound to a column in the `masterIngredientList`.

In the master ingredient sheet, there are costings in lets say column 'G'. So if the user selects Onion in `shoppingList`, in the adjacent column I'd like to get that cost for that ingredient.

I've tried to search but to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula in cell B3 of the shopping list:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A), VLOOKUP($A3:A,wa_153091_ingredients!A2:G,7,FALSE),))`

The formula will automatically populate all items on the shopping list.

**Logic**

- `Arrayformula` automatically applies the formula to every row in column B.
- `VLOOKUP($A3:A` takes the value on *each row* in column A and searches for the same value in the first column of the range `A2:G` (Column A) on sheet="wa_153091_ingredients"
- `index`=7 (return the 7th column (G) =Price)
- `is_sorted`=false: the match must be exact.
- `IF(LEN(A3:A)` tests for a value in Column A so that `vlookup` applies to rows with a value rather than every row in the sheet.

---

**Sample data - Shopping List**

[image: ShoppingList]

---

**Sample data - Ingredients**

[image: Ingredients]

Comment: looks good, could you tell me how to read that formula?

Comment: All the (unnecessary) curly brackets in that formula - argh. I've updated it for simplicity. I've also added an explanation of the logic behind the formula. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Cheers buddy!!!